# My Application (based on python tkinter) is not running at Boot time (autostart) in Raspberry Pi Os?

Tags: raspbian, python, linux, raspberry-pi-os, tkinter

I have made executable file of python tkinter application. It runs well when clicked. But I want to run it at Boot time (AutoStart) in Raspberry Pi Os.

I have tried many methods but they didn't work.

One method which I tried will other applications:

```
> sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

`@/home/pi/Downloads/exes/project2/work/dist/homeP` (@path_of_file/applicatin_name)

This didn't work with my Current application, Even no error is observed. Please help me ??

I have tried many methods but they didn't work.

Comment: is `/home/pi/Downloads/exes/project2/work/dist/homeP` an executable?

Comment: @Jaromanda X
 Yes, It is executable and it has execute permission too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a bash file to execute your Tkinter app like:

**startapp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/Downloads/exes/project2/work/dist/
python3 your_app.py
```

Then edit the `autostart` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Put your startapp in the `autostart` file:

```
@sh /home/pi/Downloads/exes/project2/work/dist/startapp.sh
```

Comment: Why is everything using `sudo`? That's supposed to be a secure command that you use sparingly.

Comment: Thanks You so much, It works.

Comment: @Elmer Thanks You so much, It works.